# A generalised Cauchy problem with Burgers' differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following:
$$u_t+uu_x=0, ~~ t>0$$

and the initial data: 
$$
u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{ if }x\in[0,1]\text{ and } 
\\
0,&\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

I have found a solution to the above problem like the following picture but is valid only for $t<2$ ...I do not know how to extend this solution for all $t>0$. Any hint please?
[image]

Remark: I have found this weak solution drawing the characteristic lines of the problem and applying a shock and fan wave where the characteristics intersect and where a "gap" is created, respectively. I confirmed this solution using Runkine - Hugionot theorem.

Comment: You should add some remarks on how you computed the shock front and its meeting the dispersion front. The image shows this, but that is not enough.

Comment: See [Burgers' equation after rarefaction wave catches up with the shock](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550698/115115) for a very similar question with a complete answer. Also related [Rarefaction and shock waves colliding in Burgers' equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1534271/115115) for a more complex example (with illustrations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After $t=2$ you have that the rarefaction segment $0<x<a(t)$ where $u(x,t)=x/t$ is directly followed by the "unchanged" segment with $u(x,t)=0$ on $a(t)<x<\infty$. The change of the phase boundary is again governed by the Runkine-Hugionot condition, that is
$$
\dot a(t)=\frac{a(t)/t+0}{2}\implies a(t)=c\sqrt{t}
$$
and from the initial condition $a(2)=2$ it follows that $c=\sqrt2$, $a(t)=\sqrt{2t}$.

See [Burgers' equation after rarefaction wave catches up with the shock](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550698/115115) for a more extensive discussion of this situation.

Comment: @dmtri The full solution is also provided in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2452803/418542)

Comment: Great help,  thanks again! It is also weird,  at least for me,  that the first shock appears in zero time,  @Harry49

Comment: @dmtri : A shock is a discontinuity in the solution. In the Burger's equation, a shock is associated to a downward jump discontinuity. You have the jump already in the initial condition.