# Later shocks in Riemann problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, initial-value-problems, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

I am following section 3.4 of Evan's book "Partial Differential Equations". In this section he considers the Burgers equation,
$$u_t + \bigl(\frac{u^2}{2}\bigr)_x = 0$$
with initial data
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0\\ 1, &0 \leq x \leq 1\\0, & x > 1\end{cases}$$
I have been able to follow how he obtains the solution for $0 \leq t \leq 2$,
$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0\\  \frac{x}{t},  & 0 <x < t\\ 1,  & t < x < 1+\frac{t}{2}\\0, & x > 1 + \frac{t}{2}\end{cases}$$
However he notes for $t \geq 2$ this solution breaks down as the rarefraction wave and the curves stemming from the initial condition $g(x) = 0$ intersect. He uses the Rankine-Hugoniot jump condition to find that
$$\dot{s}(t) = \sigma = \frac{x}{2t}$$

This is where he begins to lose me. He claims that this implies
$$\dot{s}(t) = \frac{s(t)}{2}$$
with $s(2) = 2$. He claims by solving this ODE we find
$$s(t) = \sqrt{2t}$$
and so the final solution for $t \geq 2$ is
$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0\\ \frac{x}{t}, & 0 < x < \sqrt{2t}\\0, & x > \sqrt{2t}\end{cases}$$

How does he obtain that ODE? Moreover, how does he conclude that the shock occurs at $t = 2$ (aside from graphically)?

Comment: What happens to the inequalities describing the initial piecewise function  when $t=2$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah I see, the inequality becomes empty. In general is that how we determine when the wave breaks?

Comment: The ODE is part of the Rankine Hugoniot condition; you should probably go back to the derivation of the RH condition

Comment: (The name is Evans, not Evan.)

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550698/burgers-equation-after-rarefaction-wave-catches-up-with-the-shock

Comment: (If you undelete your more recent question I have relevant comments)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks, I figured out my mistake and thought the question was ultimately not worth asking. But thank you very much!

Comment: :) best of luck finishing it!